# How to change the portion of a sphere I see along the polar axis?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]Excuse me but as a beginner I have a second probably stupid question .
I try to create an Earth view from a point along the pole axis.
Now this view will obviously show a circle whose edge is some given latitude. If I am at infinity, the edge will be the equator and when my distance to the Earth decreases, the latitude forming the edge of the circle will increase.
Unfortunately the view seems to stay always the same when I try to zoom, move, rotate the camera etc and I can't get a view which would show the Earth up to the Equator or almost to the Equator.
What commands should I use to make the edge of the circle at/near equator ?

Comment: Are you in perspective or orthographic view? Are you using the view of a camera object or just the viewport? Would you mind showing at least one screenshot of what you see and some illustration what you expect to see?

Comment: I tried both - perspective and ortographic. It doesn't seem to change anything. I use the camera view . What I see is a circle (textured earth globe) whose edge is about 30° latitude. What I would like to see is the same thing but with an edge at/near equator.

Comment: I don't know how to post a screen shot here.

Comment: You can edit your question. Then look in the top menu bar of the edit window, there is an image icon you can click on and upload an image. It will be placed at the position of your cursor. And settings of the camera etc. would be helpful, too.

Comment: I added what I see. You can notice that I see only a part of the globe - approximately from the latitude 15°N to the N pole . What I would like is to see a bigger part - ideally the whole half sphere going from the equator to the N pole what basically means to move FARTHER from the Earth along the pole axis. And I have no idea what kind of command, menu, window, tab, key etc would help to do that. This is my question.

Comment: As it says on the top left corner of the viewport *Orthographic* : you are already seeing the whole upper half of the sphere.

Comment: @Vallon When you are in orthographic view, you see the whole upper half of the sphere as Lutzi already said. The thing is, no matter if perspective or orthographic view, it is still a sphere not a flat disc. So all faces close to the equator are more or less vertical and therefore perpendicular to the camera's view. As long as you don't want to flatten your sphere, you will always have a strongly distorted view onto the low latitudes.

Comment: @Vallon My answer probably does not make this clear enough, but as you say in your comment you want to move "farther" away from the sphere. You are in orthographic view, there is no "farther" away. Orthographic view works like as if you were infinitely far away, you can only scale in or out. To actually have an effect of viewing more due to distance and perspective, you should go into camera view and move the camera further away. But as I said, orthographic is already infinitely away. The reason you are not seeing everything depends on the angle of the sphere's faces towards the viewing angle.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems to me that this is no Blender problem (and therefore off-topic for this site) but more of an issue of you not understanding how orthographic and perspective views on a sphere work...? Maybe I'm wrong, but as it appears I have to assume this.

The thing is: when viewing top down on a sphere, the closer the camera is to the sphere, the less far you will be able to "look around" it, so the less close you can view down to the equator.

Let's say, I take a sphere with a radius of 1 m sitting at the world center at (0, 0, 0). If I take a camera with a wide angle lens e.g. a focal length of 18 mm and place it above the sphere at a Z height of 2 m (and therefore 2 m above the equator of the sphere), you can see it fully in the camera's view.

Take a second camera with a focal length of 300 mm, of course this zooms in a lot more and now I have to place it around 30 m above the sphere's equator to get a similar sized sphere in the camera's view.

Here is a schematic side view of the setup (the vertical angles of view are measured for a full frame camera):

[image: side view of setup]

A close up on the sphere shows how much the distance of the camera to the sphere changes the visible range of the sphere. The closer the camera to the sphere and therefore the equator in this case, the shorter away is the horizon line from the camera and also the visible latitudes:

[image: close up on distance effect]

Looking through both of the cameras, this results in the following different appearances of the sphere and its latitudinal rings:

[image: different perspectives due to height]

I started writing this answer before you added the screenshot to your question. There you are in *Orthographic* view. The difference is basically and simply spoken that the *Perspective* view always has a certain angle of view where all the rays converge in a focal point, while the rays in *Orthographic* view are parallel and not converging:

[image: perspective vs. orthographic]

And because the *Orthographic* view is looking straight down without convergence, you can see the whole top half of the sphere - but that does not change the fact that the faces of the sphere down the curve are increasingly facing away from the view direction and thus are getting "thinner" and more distorted until on the equator they are perpendicular to the view and have an apparent width of 0, as shown below with an exaggerated low resolution sphere:

[image: apparent face size]

So with faces getting constantly smaller the further out from the pole (but using the full face width for texturing), how do you expect this to work? How should you be able to view any texture on an ultimately thin face? The only way this would be possible is to either map everything onto a flat circle instead of a sphere, or to rotate the sphere towards the viewpoint - but of course, rotating one side of the sphere towards the viewpoint will only shift the problem, because then other parts of the sphere will move out of view.

By the way, your sphere does not look like it has a very high resolution - and another thing my low resolution example above shows, the less resolution, the less faces for the curvature and since the faces are planar, the earlier the face normal will be pointing in a direction where it is not or only barely visible from the top.

Besides that, in your screenshot I can see water below India and below the Horn of Africa, I also see the upper part of South America. So to me this seems to be the complete top half of the sphere down to the equator.

Last but not least, I'm not sure how you determined that you can see only down to a latitude of approx. 15° (or 30° as you stated in an earlier comment). If you are using the mesh's edge rings centered around the pole: they are not in steps of 10°, it looks as if you used the default UV Sphere with 32 segments by 16 rings. This means between each of the rings is an angle of 11.25°, so looking from the pole at 90° the rings you see within the sphere's boundaries are 78.75°, 67.5°, 56.25°, 45°, 33.75°, 22.5° and 11.25°, leaving 0° to be the outer border - which would be the equator.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but most of what you say, I already said in the first question : "Now this view will obviously show a circle whose edge is some given latitude. If I am at infinity, the edge will be the equator and when my distance to the Earth decreases, the latitude forming the edge of the circle will increase. " I didn't want to be technical but the formula is : sin(L) = 1/(1+x) where L is the minimum visible latitude (visible edge of the sphere) and x=H/R with R radius of the sphere and H the altitude above the pole. So in technical terms my question was : "HOW can I change x in blender ?"

Comment: @Vallon I'm not sure if you read my last comment under your question. As far as I understood your question, you are not satisfied with how far down to the equator you can see and your question here "how can I change x" is mostly how you can increase x (which would mean increase the height unless you wanted to change the radius) and as I mention in the paragraphs about orthographic view and in my comment, you are at infinity - you cannot go higher and the outer edge is already the equator. Seeing below the equator is not possible.

Comment: @Vallon If I misunderstood you and you don't want to go higher but instead get **closer** to the sphere to see less i.e. that the outer edge is a higher latitude, then you cannot use orthographic view but have to switch to perspective view. In the viewport this means pressing `Numpad 5` or using a perspective camera and changing its height above the sphere. By the way, the resulting latitude according to the formula is of course limited by the resolution of your mesh, that's why for example my camera at 2 m above the sphere could only see down to a latitude of 30° and 2.5° at a height of 30 m.